# Redux Saga and Loop

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga, redux-loop

I have a use-case where I need to integrate both Redux [Saga](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga) and [Loop](https://github.com/redux-loop/redux-loop). A naive implementation of the two together does not honor the custom [CombineReducers](https://github.com/redux-loop/redux-loop/blob/v2.2.2/docs/ApiDocs.md#combinereducersreducersmap-initialstate-accessor-modifier) of Loop, so when side-effects are introduced, the hidden array that stores Loop effects is exposed, so the root of the state tree for a reducer becomes an array (`0` has the normal state, `1` has the side effects).

So question being. How do I have them both play nice in the same sandbox?

Comment: Curious why you need both?

Comment: Just integration challenges